# How to pass dynamic data between the scenarios in a specification using gauge

Tags: java, maven, automation, gauge

I need to pass a String value from one scenario to another.

Is that possible in Gauge?

Scenario 1: Login with username and password

Scenario 2: Username should be visible on the top right corner of the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes gauge has the special feature for that called "[Data Store](https://docs.gauge.org/latest/writing-specifications.html#data-store)" where you can dynamically pass the values between scenarios and specs too.

Basically, gauge has 3 types of data stores.

1. `ScenarioStore` - You can pass values between the steps inside a scenario. At the end of the scenario, that value and the data store variable will be disappear.
2. `SpecStore` - You can pass values between the scenarios inside a specification. At the end of the specification, that value and the data store variable will be disappear.
3. `SuiteStore` - You can pass values between the specifications. At the end of the test suite, that value and the data store variable will be disappear.

Click [here](https://docs.gauge.org/latest/writing-specifications.html#data-store) to implement data stores in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible. Data stores can be used for that